# Как методу распознать что вернуть? View или JSON?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

У меня есть метод. В одном случае он должен возвращать обычную View, а в другом - JSON данные. Как метод определит когда его вызвали для отрисовки View, а когда для возврата данных JSON?

Comment: а почему не два метода?

Comment: требование такое. Там 2 метода почти с идентичным функционалом, только один возвращает модель, а второй json

Comment: ну тогда передавайте параметр на основании которого принимайте соответствующее решение

Comment: а другого, более изящного способа нет?

Comment: либо 2 разных урла, либо один но с параметром. я больше ничего придумать не могу

Comment: понял, спасибо. Можете написать ответ - приму его

Comment: если `JSON` нужен в ответ на `ajax` запрос то можно попробовать воспользоваться готовой переменной `Request.IsAjaxRequest` а в остальных случаях  отдавать `View`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

как мне кажется есть несколько возможных вариантов:

1. С клиента на сервере пересылать параметр, на основании значения которого сервер ответит либо готовой разметкой или же вернет `json`.
2. Сделать на сервере 2 разных метода, например: `public ActionResult GetView()` & `public ActionResult GetJSON()` при обращении к которым отдавать именно то что надо
3. Если `json` необходим в ответ на `ajax`запрос то тогда можно воспользоваться значением переменной `Request.IsAjaxRequest`

Answer (score 3):

Можно с клиента передавать заголовок `Accept`

Например:

```
$http.get('url/path', {}, {Accept: 'text/html'});
$http.get('url/path', {}, {Accept: 'application/json'});
```

А в контроллере

```
var accept = Request.Headers["accept"];
```

И его уже обрабатывать.

Comment: если речь об `ajax` то можно смотреть `Request.IsAjaxRequest`

Comment: @Bald, вполне возможно, что оба варианта через `ajax` грузятся. Тогда в обоих случаях будет `true`. Но если один это не так - Ваш вариант проще.